# Cannot print full RejectedRecords

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-timestream

I try to write records into my timestream database.
My problem is that i get an `Cannot read httpResponse` of undefined even if i did the same thing as they describe in their guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/code-samples.write.html#code-samples.write.rejectedRecordException

```
 const timestreamParams = {
      DatabaseName: db_name,
      TableName: TimeSpanRawE[table_name],
      Records: chunk,
    }
    let request = writeClient.writeRecords(timestreamParams).promise()
    await request.then(
      (data) => {
        return ok(data)
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('Error writing records:', error)
        if (error.code === 'RejectedRecordsException') {
          const responsePayload = JSON.parse(
            //@ts-ignore
            request.response.httpResponse.body.toString()
          )
          console.log('RejectedRecords: ', responsePayload.RejectedRecords)
          console.log('Other records were written successfully. ')
        }
        return err({ error, params })
      }
    )
```

So, how can i read the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your request variable incorrectly. The promise shouldn't be included in the request variable. It should be like this:

```
let request = writeClient.writeRecords(timestreamParams).promise()
```

The promise can then be called like this:

```
await request.promise().then( 
   ...
)
```